# ¿Cómo acumular los datos de una función INPUT en un bucle?

Tags: python, bucles, input

Soy nuevo en python 3 y tenía la duda de como acumular (para que se vayan sumando) los valores introducidos a una función `int(input())` que esté dentro de un bucle. Hice este código como ejemplo:

```
while x: 
  y = int(input("Ingrese el valor "))
    
  if y < 0:
    print("Ingrese un valor válido")
    continue
  elif y == 0:
    break
```

La idea era que, al introducir el número 0, el código acabase y mostrara la suma de los valores introducidos. Agradezco mucho la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podrías crear una variable fuera del while en la que vayas acumulando los valores

```
total = 0
while True:
    v = int(input("Ingrese el valor "))
    if  v < 0:
        print("Ingrese un valor válido")
        continue
    
    if v == 0:
        print(f"total {total}")
        break
    
    total = total + v
```

Comment: Me funcionó perfecto Mario, te agradezco mucho.